# How to find functions imported from torch._C in source code

Tags: pytorch

I'm trying to track down the implementation of `torch.nn.NLLLoss` in the source code. I got as far as a call to `torch._C.nll_loss` in the function `nll_loss` in the file `torch.nn.functional`. But I can't find a place where _C is created.

Anyone have any info on this?

Comment: It's an extension, see here: https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/031412a14b7c20e9030b00c26f30c5524a0eb028/setup.py#L747. Finding the ultimate definition is quite a rabbit hole though, https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/master/aten/src/ATen/nn.yaml mentions ClassNLLCriterion, which appears to be in https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/master/aten/src/THNN/generic/ClassNLLCriterion.c

Comment: Jeez, that's tough to track down. Thanks so much for the help, if you post that as an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 6):

Take a look at [A Tour of PyTorch Internals](http://pytorch.org/2017/05/11/Internals.html) on the PyTorch blog. Relevant excerpt:

> PyTorch defines a new package torch. In this post we will consider the ._C module. This module is known as an “extension module” - a Python module written in C. Such modules allow us to define new built-in object types (e.g. the Tensor) and to call C/C++ functions.
>
> The ._C module is defined in torch/csrc/Module.cpp. The init_C() / PyInit__C() function creates the module and adds the method definitions as appropriate. This module is passed around to a number of different __init() functions that add further objects to the module, register new types, etc.

[Part II](http://pytorch.org/2017/06/27/Internals2.html) to that post goes into detail about the build system. In the section on NN modules, it says

> Briefly, let’s touch on the last part of the build_deps command: generate_nn_wrappers(). We bind into the backend libraries using PyTorch’s custom cwrap tooling, which we touched upon in a previous post. For binding TH and THC we manually write the YAML declarations for each function. However, due to the relative simplicity of the THNN and THCUNN libraries, we auto-generate both the cwrap declarations and the resulting C++ code.
>
> The reason we copy the THNN.h and THCUNN.h header files into torch/lib is that this is where the generate_nn_wrappers() code expects these files to be located. generate_nn_wrappers() does a few things:
>
> - Parses the header files, generating cwrap YAML declarations and writing them to output .cwrap files
> - Calls cwrap with the appropriate plugins on these .cwrap files to generate source code for each
> - Parses the headers a second time to generate THNN_generic.h - a library that takes THPP Tensors, PyTorch’s “generic” C++ Tensor Library, and calls into the appropriate THNN/THCUNN library function based on the dynamic type of the Tensor

Perhaps not that helpful without the context, but I don't think I should copy the entire post here.

When I tried to track down the definition of NLLLoss without having read those posts, I ended up at [aten/src/THNN/generic/ClassNLLCriterion.c](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/master/aten/src/THNN/generic/ClassNLLCriterion.c), via [aten/src/ATen/nn.yaml](http://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/master/aten/src/ATen/nn.yaml). The latter is probably the YAML the second post talks about, but I haven't checked.

Comment: I also wrote an article about the code base: http://blog.christianperone.com/2018/03/pytorch-internal-architecture-tour/

Answer (score 1):

TL; DR: If you want to find out how a function is implemented in C code, you can check the github repository of Pytorch here:

https://github.com/torch/nn/tree/master/lib/THNN/generic